# Custom plugin contact form connecting to mailchimp API

Tags: custom-post-types, forms, api

Hi everyone im new to api and i am having a hard time wrapping this code that i got on the internet . i am creating a custom plugin in wordpress and i am trying to connect it to the api using mailchimp but it didn't work.
here's the code.

```
<?php

/**
 * Plugin Name: Custom Form with API
 * Description: Connecting custom post type form with API
 * Author:
 * Version: 1.0
 * 
 */


add_action('admin_menu', 'test_plugin_setup_menu');

function test_plugin_setup_menu(){
    add_menu_page( 'Test Plugin Page', 'Contact Form API', 'manage_options', 'test-plugin', 'test_init' );
  
  
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', plugins_url( 'style.css' , __FILE__ ));

}
function test_init(){
    test_handle_post();
?>

    
<div class="container">
      <span class="big-circle"></span>
      <img src="img/shape.png" class="square" alt="" />
      <div class="form">
        <div class="contact-info">
          <h3 class="title">Let's get in touch</h3>
          <p class="text">
           A new API that handle request and make your life easier
          </p>

          <div class="info">
            <div class="information">
              <img src="img/location.png" class="icon" alt="" />
            
            </div>
            <div class="information">
              <img src="img/email.png" class="icon" alt="" />
             
            </div>
            <div class="information">
              <img src="img/phone.png" class="icon" alt="" />
             
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="social-media">
            <p>Connect with us :</p>
            <div class="social-icons">
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="contact-form">
          <span class="circle one"></span>
          <span class="circle two"></span>

          <form method="POST" action="" autocomplete="off">
            <h3 class="title">Contact form with API</h3>
            <div class="input-container">
              <input type="text" name="name" class="input" placeholder="name"/>
            
              <span>firstname</span>
            </div>
          
            <div class="input-container">
              <input type="email" name="email" class="input" placeholder="email"/>
             
              <span>Email</span>
            </div>
            <div class="input-container">
              <input type="tel" name="phone" class="input" placeholder="phone"/>
            
              <span>Phone</span>
            </div>
          
            <input type="submit" name="submit_message" value="Send Message" class="btn" />
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}

    function test_handle_post(){

    
if(isset($_POST['submit_message'])){

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    if(!empty($email) && !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false){
        // MailChimp API credentials
        // $apiKey = '';
        // $listID = '';
        
      $list_id = '';

      $response = wp_remote_request( 
        'https://' . substr($api,strpos($api,'-')+1) . '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/' . $list_id . '/members/' . md5(strtolower($email)),
        array(
          'method' => 'PUT',
          'headers' => array(
            'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode( 'user:'. $api )
          ),
          'body' => json_encode(
            array(
              'email_address' => , // change the email here
              'status' => 'subscribed' // unsubscribed, pending
            )
          )
        )
      );

      if( 'OK' === wp_remote_retrieve_response_message( $response ) ) {
        echo 'The user has been successfully subscribed.';
      }
      }
    }
  } 
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code like this

```php
// Enter here the MailChimp API key
$apiKey = "";
// Enter here Mailchimp list id
$list_id = "";

$server = explode( '-', $apiKey );

$url = 'https://' . $server[1] . '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/' . $list_id . '/members/';

$response = wp_remote_post(
    $url,
    [
        'method'      => 'POST',
        'data_format' => 'body',
        'timeout'     => 45,
        'headers'     => [
            'Authorization' => 'apikey ' . $apiKey,
            'Content-Type'  => 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        ],
        'body'        => json_encode(
            [
                'email_address' => '',//email
                'status'        => 'subscribed',
                'status_if_new' => 'subscribed',
                'merge_fields'  => [
                    'FNAME' => '',// first name
                    'LNAME' => '',// last name
                    'PHONE' => ''//phone
                ]
            ]
        )
    ]
);
```

Comment: Thank you sir fix it. i have question i want to make the api key dynamic which means i will not add the api key and list id in the code i have added a admin menu in the admin side which means the api will be added there not in the code. Thank  you in advance!

Comment: You will be able to take the API key from the admin menu. You can also pull all the list IDs from the API key, which is a different question.

You have to pass the API key and list. Doesn't matter where you are passing. It could be static or dynamic.

Comment: Thanks for the response i already fix my problem by saving the api key into the database.  thank you.